# combining two codes targeting images

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have two working codes that do two things to the images in my word-press site. However they don't work when I use them both as is. I can't seem to combine them and keep the functionality of both.

Outputs all the images in my word-press post with the last one wrapped in #last-img

```
<?php
    preg_match_all('/(<img [^>]*>)/', get_the_content(), $images);

    for( $i=0; isset($images[1]) && $i < count($images[1]); $i++ ) {
        if ($i == end(array_keys($images[1]))) {
            echo sprintf('<div id="last-img">%s</div>', $images[1][$i]);
            continue;
        }
        echo $images[1][$i];
    }
?>
```

puts the last image as the background of #last-img

```
<?php
 preg_match_all('/src="([^"]*)"/i', get_the_content(), $images);
?>

<div id="last-img" style="background:url(<?php echo $images[1][count($images[1])-1] )"> ... </div>
```

I want to display all the images and have the last image as the background of #last-img

Comment: I'm following your code but I don't see the second part where it becomes the background of #last-img. Or what string does your code save it under

Comment: Ic, Well it does the first part, but I need the last image to become the background-image for #last-img the way I have it the best I would get is the last image twice

Comment: user3550879   Did you checked the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
<?php
    preg_match_all('/(<img [^>]*>)/', get_the_content(), $images);
    preg_match_all('/src="([^"]*)"/i', get_the_content(), $images1);
    $count = count($images[1]);
    $count1 = count($images1[1]);
    foreach($images[1] as $k=> $img){
        if($k == $count-1){
            $format = '<div id="last-img" style="background:url(%s)"> ... </div>'; // Or $format = "<div id='last-img' style='background:url(%s)'> ... </div>";
            $image = $images1[1][$count1-1];
            echo sprintf($format,$image);
        }else{
            echo $img;
        }
    }
?>
```

Or

```
<?php
    preg_match_all('/(<img [^>]*>)/', get_the_content(), $images);
    preg_match_all('/src="([^"]*)"/i', get_the_content(), $images1);
    $count = count($images[1]);
    $count1 = count($images1[1]);
    foreach($images[1] as $k=> $img){
            echo $img;
    }
    $format = '<div id="last-img" style="background:url(%s)"> ... </div>'; // Or $format = "<div id='last-img' style='background:url(%s)'> ... </div>";
    $image = $images1[1][$count1-1];
    echo sprintf($format,$image);
?>
```

Comment: what is the main difference between the two?

Comment: 1. first one iterate through first preg_match array and print all the images and when last one is came then it add background image (skips last image(instead of that background image come)).  2. it will also iterates on the same but here all images will print and then background will come(skips no images and either your first match array  will have images or not background will come)